# How to create a Holoviews app with multiple independent DynamicMap plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to create a grid layout (say 2x2) of plots of the DynamicMap type using holoviews. 
This is to be served as a Holoviews/Bokeh app.

After creating my dmaps I Lay them out using

```
layout = hv.Layout([dmap1, dmap2]).cols(2)
```

this layout generates a two plots side-by-side
The problem I am facing is that by default, the widgets for each Dynamic Map get clustered to the rightof the row , with no visual association to the plots (the maps toolbars also get combined into just one).

Moreover, If I pass more than two dmaps to the layout, I get an error:

```
TypeError: DynamicMap does not accept AdjointLayout type, data elements have to be a ('ViewableElement', 'NdMapping', 'Layout').
```

I am using the renderer in server mode:

```
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
renderer = renderer.instance(mode='server')
```

In summary, I want to have a grid of more than 2 **independently** controlable dynamical plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, so let me start out answering this question:

> the widgets for each Dynamic Map get clustered to the right of the row

If you want independent sets of widgets you will have to construct each set of widgets manually and compose the resulting bokeh models yourself. This example demonstrates this approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')

dmap1 = hv.DynamicMap(lambda x: hv.Curve(np.random.rand(10)), kdims='x').redim.range(x=(0,5))
dmap2 = hv.DynamicMap(lambda y: hv.Scatter(np.random.rand(10)), kdims='y').redim.range(x=(0,5))

widget1 = renderer.get_widget(dmap1, None, position='above').state
widget2 = renderer.get_widget(dmap2, None, position='above').state

r = row(widget1, widget2)

doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(r)
```

We create two independent DynamicMaps, then use the renderer to generate separate plots and widgets and then compose them using the bokeh row layout. As you can see we can also define a position for the widgets so instead of laying them out on the right they are on top.

> the maps toolbars also get combined into just one

In [this recent PR](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/2289) a new `merge_tools` option was added to allow having separate toolbars in a single Layout.

> Moreover, If I pass more than two dmaps to the layout, I get an error:

This is probably due to returning an adjoined object, which is not allowed inside a DynamicMap at the moment. Are you by any chance using the `.hist` method? If so try calling it on the `DynamicMap` instead of having the `DynamicMap` return an object with an adjoined `Histogram`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @philippjfr. But what about having multiple rows? Just keep adding roots?

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to create the widgets:  rmeans_w = renderer.get_widget(rmeans, None, position='above').state
AttributeError: 'BokehSelectionWidget' object has no attribute 'state'

Comment: What about more complex layouts? Way are you passing to row only the widgets? and not the plots? Bokeh has a layout function which does not seem to accept hv dmaps: ValueError: Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into a layout.
                Tried to insert: :DynamicMap   [Exchanges,Symbols,Window] of type <class 'holoviews.core.spaces.DynamicMap'>

Comment: >I am getting this error when trying to create the widgets

Are you sure you made an instance of renderer in 'server' mode using:

    renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')

>Way are you passing to row only the widgets?

These ``.state`` on a BokehServerWidget contains a bokeh layout of both the plot and the widgets. If you just want the plot you can use ``renderer.get_plot(dmap).state``.

Comment: Yes I am using renderer in server mode: 
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
renderer = renderer.instance(mode='server')

Comment: Ok found it! I was creating the renderer, the getting the widgets and only at the end, turning the renderer to 'server' mode. Thanks again

Comment: @philippjfr, thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'HoloViews' object has no attribute 'state'`. This is different from what @fccoelho saw before. The `get_wedget` method seems to return a HoloViews object, which has no attribute 'state'.

Comment: You're right, as of HoloViews 1.13.0, HoloViews widgets are built on Panel. I'll update the post when I get a chance.